# Create a custom Identify dialog

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, polygon, c#

How can I check if a point belongs to a polygon? I want to create a custom identify tool with edit option. I am using C# and ArcMap 10.

My idea is to click on the polygon (building/park/etc) in ArcMap and if the cursor coordinates belongs to polygon, get its parameters from building_layer for further checking (number of building, street name).

Answer (score 3):

You will want to create a **ToolControl** button that allows you to click on a map as opposed to a button which does something when you click on it. Then grab the point, create a **spatialfilter** and query your polygon layer, this returns a **Feature** object which you can return the various address components and populate some form that you created.  The bold words are the key interfaces you need to go away and research. There are many examples in the Help and on the various forums.

Comment: How can I check if polygon is selected? Can you post some code?

Comment: Having set the spatialfilter you pass that to the IfeatureLayer.Search() method and that will return an IFeatureCursor which you cycle through getting any Features that fulfilled the spatial relationship (in your case point intersects polygon).

Comment: I really have problem with this situation. public IPoint GetMapCoordinatesFromScreenCoordinates(IPoint screenPoint, IActiveView activeView)
        {Polygon pol = new Polygon();
                ISpatialFilter sp = new SpatialFilterClass();
                sp.Geometry = screenPoint;
                sp.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelCrosses;
                
                ITopologicalOperator topOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)screenPoint;
                IGeometry resultGeom = (IGeometry)topOperator.Intersect(pol, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension);

Comment: TopoOp is the wrong thing to use. Set your spatial filter relationship to be intersect and pass that into search method on feature layer to get the cursor. If the cursor contains features then that point intersected those polygons.

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000046000000 I tried this and feature is always null

Comment: That is the right code to use. If null then it would suggest that either the point does not intersect or you are not using the correct point. Maybe you could edit your question and upload your code?

Comment: Thank you, all I needed was point = activeView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint((int)point.X, (int)point.Y); everything works with this line